# Is there a word for a monogram of the entire alphabet?

Tags: symbols

I am fascinated by the attached image but I am not sure what to call it. I have seen it labeled as a monogram of the alphabet, however that sounds bulky. As it contains all of the letters I want to call it an omnigram, would that be correct?

Bonus: If anyone has come across this image, do you have any idea of it's  origin?

[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble finding W... is it just the upside-down M? That doesn't seem quite right, since W usually doesn't have parallel left and right sides.

Comment: Maybe it’s the bottoms of the two circles.

Comment: I've not come across *U* as stylized in this monogram. It's really not all that impressive, since some of the letters are highly stylized.

Comment: It's related to a [pangram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pangram) - maybe it should be called a pangraph?

Answer (score 2):

A [monogram](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/monogram) is a design consisting of two or more alphabetic letters combined or interlaced, and an [omnigram](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=omnigram) is an email that is sent to a large audience when it really concerns only one person.  So therefore the image is a *monogram*.

A point of note is that it doesn't just have the A to Z in the monogram.  [It also has 1 to 9](http://www.imgur.com/gallery/dCsiu).

Answer (score 0):

I have this as a tattoo, W is in there, I hav attached a video illustrating all of the letters. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z07CSCALs1s

Comment: Should probably be a comment on the question rather than an answer.